# Qual o comando usando *ngIf para fazer uma verificação maior e menor

Tags: angular, ionic2

Estou usando o ngIF apenas para mudar a cor do objeto, mas eu estou precisando criar uma que o resultado.MediaTotal seja menor que 70 e maior que 50.
Qual é a sintaxe correta pra fazer isso: *ngIf="resultado.MediaTotal < 70 and > 50"

```
<p *ngIf="resultado.MediaTotal > 70" style="color:green">{{resultado.MediaTotal}} </p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recomendo usar [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) em vez de `ngIf` pra estilizar seus componentes dinamicamente. Vamos imaginar um cenário onde você tem vários estilos, você teria que fazer vários componentes iguais mudando apenas o estilo deles, isso é uma má prática pois você está repetindo código.

Exemplo:

```
<p [ngClass]="getClass()">{{resultado.mediaTotal}}</p>
```

Note que não estamos fazendo nenhuma validação no html, podemos deixar essa parte pro `component`, onde nesse exemplo criei a função `getClass()`

No seu Component/Page você faria algo como:

```
 getClass(){
    if(this.resultado.mediaTotal > 50 && this.resultado.mediaTotal < 70)
      return 'my-style-green'
    if(this.resultado.mediaTotal < 50)
      return 'my-style-red'
  }
```

Note que ele está retornando uma string, essa string é sua classe que você pode colocar no css da sua página.

```
.my-style-green{
     color: green;
 }
 .my-style-red{
     color: red;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Você deve utilizar o operador lógico `&&`

```
<p 
    *ngIf="resultado.MediaTotal > 50 && resultado.MediaTotal < 70"
    style="color:green">
        {{resultado.MediaTotal}
</p>
```